# Numpy aggregate function shims, typing, and np.sort() in Numba

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, types, numba

I'm working with Numba (0.44) and Numpy in `nopython` mode. Presently, Numba doesn't support Numpy aggregation functions across an arbitrary axis, it only supports computing these aggregates over a whole array. Given the situation, I decided to take a crack and creating some shims.

In code:

```
np.min(array) # This works with Numba 0.44
np.min(array, axis = 0) # This does not work with Numba 0.44 (no axis argument allowed)
```

Here's an example of a shim, designed to reproduce `np.min(array)`:

```
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython = True)
def npmin (X, axis = -1):
    """
    Shim for broadcastable np.min(). 
    Allows np.min(array), np.min(array, axis = 0), and np.min(array, axis = 1)
    Note that the argument axis = -1 computes on the entire array.
    """
    if axis == 0:
        _min = np.sort(X.transpose())[:,0]
    elif axis == 1:
        _min = np.sort(X)[:,0]
    else:
        _min = np.sort(np.sort(X)[:,0])[0]
    return _min
```

Without Numba, the shim works as expected and recapitulates the behavior of `np.min()` upto a 2D array. Note that I'm using `axis = -1` as a means of allowing the summing of the entire array – similar behavior to invoking `np.min(array)` without an `axis` argument.

Unfortunately, once I throw Numba into the mix, i get an error. Here's the trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shims.py", line 81, in <module>
    _min = npmin(a)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 348, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 315, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/six.py", line 658, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of Function(<function sort at 0x10abd5ea0>) with argument(s) of type(s): (array(int64, 2d, F))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: resolving callee type: Function(<function sort at 0x10abd5ea0>)
[2] During: typing of call at shims.py (27)


File "shims.py", line 27:
def npmin (X, axis = -1):
    <source elided>
    if axis == 0:
        _min = np.sort(X.transpose())[:,0]
        ^

This is not usually a problem with Numba itself but instead often caused by
the use of unsupported features or an issue in resolving types.

To see Python/NumPy features supported by the latest release of Numba visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html
and
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html

For more information about typing errors and how to debug them visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/troubleshoot.html#my-code-doesn-t-compile

If you think your code should work with Numba, please report the error message
and traceback, along with a minimal reproducer at:
https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/new
```

I've verified that all the functions I'm using and their respective arguments are supported in Numba 0.44. Of course, the stack trace *says* the issue is with my call to `np.sort(array)`, but I suspect this may be a typing issue because the function can return either a scalar (without axis argument) or 2D-array (with axis argument).

That said, I have a few of questions:

- Is there an issue with my implementation; can anyone pinpoint an unsupported feature I'm using, as suggested by the stack trace?
- Or rather, does this appear to be a bug with Numba?
- More generally, are these kinds of shims presently possible with Numba (0.44)?

Comment: I've opened up an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4248#issue-462833969) and will report back on any headway that's made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative shim for 2d arrays:

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def npmin2(X, axis=0):
    if axis == 0:
        _min = np.empty(X.shape[1])
        for i in range(X.shape[1]):
            _min[i] = np.min(X[:,i])
    elif axis == 1:
        _min = np.empty(X.shape[0])
        for i in range(X.shape[0]):
            _min[i] = np.min(X[i,:])

    return _min
```

although you'll have to figure out a workaround for the `axis=-1` case, because that's going to return a scalar, and the other arguments will return arrays and Numba will not be able to "unify" the return type into something consistent.

The performance, on my machine at least, seems to be roughly comparable to just calling the equivalent `np.min`, with sometimes `np.min` being faster and other times `npmin2` winning out, depending on the input array size and axis.